# Run background Task until object falls out of scope

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to implement a class which runs a background task, looping and updating the state of the class. Once the class falls out of scope, running the background task has no value, so I would like to exit the loop and allow the task to complete and release the thread.

```
public class ValueProvider
{
    private ConfigurationReloadToken _reloadToken = new ConfigurationReloadToken();

    public string Value {get; private set;}

    public IChangeToken ChangeToken => _reloadToken;

    public void Load()
    {
        // Load the initial value.
        Value = "Foo";            

        // Watch for changes to and reload the value.
        WatchForChanges();
    }

    private void WatchForChanges() => Task.Run(WatchAsync);

    private async Task WatchAsync()
    {   
        var stillInScope = true;
        while(stillInScope)
        {
            // Watch for new values.
            Value = await LoadNewValueAsync();

            // Signal a change.
            OnReload();
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> LoadNewValueAsync()
    {
        // Simulate an actual lookup which blocks until a new value is available.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        return "Bar";
    }

    private void OnReload()
    {
        var previousToken = Interlocked.Exchange(
            ref _reloadToken,
            new ConfigurationReloadToken());
        previousToken.OnReload();
    }
}
```

Since the created `Task` has a reference to the `ValueProvider`, the instance will never fall out of scope. The solution probably has to include accessing the `ValueProvider` from the background task via a `WeakReference<T>` to allow it to go out of scope, but I'm open to solutions.

How can I detect that the "foreground" object has fallen out of scope and stop the accompanied background task?

Comment: By `has fallen out of scope` you mean `is eligible for garbage collection`? Or `has been garbage collected`? Or something else?

Comment: If it is ok for it to be used with "using" directive, you could implement the Disposable pattern ...

Comment: @mjwills I would technically mean "is eligible for garbage collection", but it's a bit more nuanced that this; I mean "not accessible by any objects other than the background task".

Comment: @Fildor I would normally have used `IDisposable` for this kind of cleanup, but I don't have a deterministic scope.

Comment: What is your concern with using `WeakReference` (which is the usual solution to this style of problem)?

Comment: `WeakReference` just makes the code considerably harder to write and reason about. I'm open to alternatives or "clever" usages of `WeakReference`.

Comment: "harder to write and reason about" ... well, if your ValueProvider does both, yes. But I think complexity shrinks considerably, if you have your ValueProvider provide a value and nothing more. Factor out the watching would be my first move.